# typeof operator doesn't seem to work on TC or ideone compilers

Tags: c++, typeof

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
--------------------------
---------------------------
#include<map>
-----------------
#include<iterator>
-------------------------
using namespace std;
------------------------------------

int main(){

map<int,int>M;
M[1]=2;
M[3]=4;
M[4]=5;
M[2]=3;
for(typeof(M.begin()) it = (M).begin(); it != (M).end(); ++it);
   cout<<it->second;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry there was a problem in copying the code

Comment: i use it->second in that line;rest of the code must work i believe

Comment: `typeof` is a [C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).

Comment: That would not be the only reason for this code to not compile. Care to fix your post ?

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid C++ code. Also, `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a valid library header and more than likely an internal standard library implementation header from libstdc++, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-works-in-c).

Comment: @quantdev if i cud fix my code,i woudnt have been here in the first place

Comment: @RaghavSharma the "post not the "code", hopefully for you people edited the post for you (they dont have too). Still, you can improve it by removing the useless `-------------------`

Answer (score 3):

C++ language does not have `typeof` operator. It is a GCC-specific extension of C language. C++11 feature with the same (or very similar) functionality is `decltype`. Use `decltype` in C++ code, not `typeof`.

However, in your particular case `auto` might be a more appropriate alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use auto.

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->second << endl;
```

or you can use iterators.

```
map<int, int>::iterator it;

for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->second << endl;
```

Comment: May as well throw in `for (auto const& x : m) { std::cout << x.second << '\n'; }`. Examples with `std::for_each` with lambda and functors withheld for sanity (the madness has to end somewhere).

Comment: He cannot write the ordinary loop so I give him this answer ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, Although `std::for_each` still has some potential: `std::for_each(m, [](const auto &p) {/*blah*/});` I'm really not sure what it would offer over range-based for loops at that point, though, especially with being able to omit the type in the latter.

Comment: @mohaned Its fine. Both of your snips are sufficient. There are *lots* of ways to enumerate in modern C++. Those are more-than-sufficient for a beginner in C++. +1.

Comment: @chris it would offer nothing but yet-more-ways to enumerate. Enumeration is a Chinese buffet with all the ways we have now in C++11. I prefer range based, but alas I only get to use it in off-work practice, as I still can't get the neanderthals at work to move to a VS that supports C++11.

Comment: @mohaned i know i can do it the way u are suggesting i wanna figure out a way to use typeof since it helps in complex STL declarations and maybe used for convenient macro declaration

Comment: @RaghavSharma I think auto is very simple to use, read the answers below.

Comment: @RaghavSharma, How does using `M.begin()` twice in the same declaration make the code any clearer?

Comment: @chris its perfectly fine to use M.begin() twice;see the usage of typeof

Answer (score 0):

Using an online compiler your mileage may vary.

Using `man gcc | grep "\-std"` gives us this:

> ```
>    -std=
>        extensions that do not contradict it.  For example, -std=c90 turns
>        the standard. For example -std=gnu90 -Wpedantic warns about C++
>        style // comments, while -std=gnu99 -Wpedantic does not.
>            GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.
> ```

This means that `-std=gnu++98` is the default mode when `-std` is not specified. Although specifying any of the `c++xx` standards will cause it not to compile. You can fix this by using `gnu++xx` instead (which enables [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).) This means that your code will not compile using Ideone's C++11 mode (which adds `-std=c++11`), but it will in the C++ 4.8.1 mode (which most likely does not add any `-std` switch). Using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), you can modify the invocation yourself and test these options.

Alternatively, if you choose not to use `gnu++xx`, try `__typeof__`.

As others have already stated, if you are C++11 mode, it is idiomatic to use `auto` in an iterator loop:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
```