# why is the size of vector is out of range

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <int> v;
    vector<int> :: iterator ip;
    v.push_back(2);
    for(int i=3;i<=32000;i+=2)
    {
        int top;
        top = sqrt(i)+1;
        int flag=0;
        if(*ip>top) break;
        if(i%*ip==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<v.at(n)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can you please explain me why my code is getting runtime error.
is size of the vector is getting out of range ??
I dont know why i am getting wrong answer in this code although my code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Which line did the program stop on when you ran it in a debugger?

Comment: Add a try catch and print out the exception, what does the exception say ?

Comment: You don't initialize `ip`, so `*ip > top` does ... what? You also don't bounds check user input `n`.

Comment: You do not initialize the iterator ip but try to get the value at the position this iterator points to. This can't work.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- what in the world... ?

Comment: Found some info on that odd include: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25311011/10077

Answer (score 2):

You're dereferencing an uninitialized iterator, you want something more like:

```
vector<int>::iterator ip = v.begin();
```

Comment: That's part of the story. This will keep getting invalidated whenever the vector grows.

Comment: Only works if v contains a value, i.e. first the push_back(2) from above, then your line of code.

Comment: Except that if the vector re-sizes, it will probably invalidate the iterator. Not even sure what they are trying to do, but an index is probably simpler.