# What does ~ exactly do when used in bit wise operations?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-xor

What is the difference between `~i` and `INT_MAX^i` 
Both give the same no. in binary but when we print the no. the output is different as shown in the code below

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void binary(int x)
{
int i=30;
while(i>=0)
{
    if(x&(1<<i))
      cout<<'1';
    else
      cout<<'0';
    i--;  
}
cout<<endl;
}
int main() {
  int i=31;
  int j=INT_MAX;
  int k=j^i;
  int g=~i;
  binary(j);
  binary(i);
  binary(k);
  binary(g);
  cout<<k<<endl<<g;
 return 0;
}
```

I get the output as

```
1111111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000011111
1111111111111111111111111100000
1111111111111111111111111100000  
2147483616
-32
```

Why are k and g different?

Comment: `~` is a `NOT` operator. `^` is a `XOR` operator.

Comment: So wat does ~ do exactly?

Comment: Simplest operation ever: it inverts each bit.

Comment: Inversion. Consider that your new number is 1 - your old number.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just getting a lil lazy I guess... Good answer btw

Comment: Also, [quit `#include`ing internal implementation-specific headers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25311052/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  look closely, it is correct

Comment: @RavishMahur _"look closely, it is correct "_ No, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`  is _not correct_.

Answer (score 7):

`K` and `g` are different - the most significant bit is different. You do not display it since you show only 31 bits. In `k` the most significant bit is 0 (as the result of XOR of two 0's). In `g` it is 1 as the result of negation of 0 (the most significant bit of `i`).

Answer (score 3):

Your test is flawed. If you output *all* of the integer's bits, you'll [see that the values are not the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/811553a113faa2ff).

You'll also now see that *NOT* and *XOR* are not the same operation.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `i = 31` in your binary function; it is not printing the whole number. You will then see that `k` and `g` are not the same; `g` has the 'negative' flag (1) on the end.

Integers use the 32nd bit to indicate if the number is positive or negative. You are only printing 31 bits.

`~` is bitwise NOT; ~11100 = ~00011
`^` is bitwise XOR, or true if only one or the other

Answer (score 1):

`~` is bitwise `NOT`, it will *flip all the bits*

Example

```
 a:  010101
~a:  101010
```

`^` is `XOR`, it means that a bit will be `1` *iff* one bit is `0` and the other is `1`, otherwise it will set to `0`.

```
  a: 010101
  b: 001100
a^b: 011001
```

Comment: @Ravish: U did not write the question carefully

Comment: I read the question just fine, I'm explaining how the operators work. The way you generated your output is incorrect, so the premise of your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You want UINT_MAX. And you want to use unsigned int's INT_MAX only does not have the signed bit set. ~ will flip all the bits, but ^ will leave the sign bit alone because it is not set in INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false:

> `~i` and `INT_MAX^i` ... Both give the same no. in binary

The reason it *appears* that they give the same number in binary
is because you printed out only 31 of the 32 bits of each number.
You did not print the sign bit.

The sign bit of `INT_MAX` is 0 (indicating a positive signed integer) 
and is is not changed during `INT_MAX^i`
because the sign bit of `i` also is 0,
and the XOR of two zeros is 0.

The sign bit of `~i` is 1 because the sign bit of `i` was 0 and the
`~` operation flipped it.

If you printed all 32 bits you would see this difference in the binary output.