# Inserting pair in std::set is inconsistent (doesn't recognize <pair>.second)

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdset

This code performs differently if I add a condition:

**First case:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct comp
{
    bool operator()(pair<int,pair<int,int> > a, pair<int,pair<int,int> > b)
    {
        return a.first>b.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<pair<int,pair<int,int>>,comp> s;
    auto d = s.insert({4,{6,10}});
    cout<<(d.first)->first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.second<<endl;
    d = s.insert({4,{0,4}});
    cout<<(d.first)->first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.second<<endl;
}
```

*Output*:

```
4 6 10
4 6 10
```

**Second case:** (with condition on .second)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct comp
{
    bool operator()(pair<int,pair<int,int> > a, pair<int,pair<int,int> > b)
    {
        if(a.first==b.first)
            return a.second.first<b.second.first;
        return a.first>b.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<pair<int,pair<int,int>>,comp> s;
    auto d = s.insert({4,{6,10}});
    cout<<(d.first)->first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.second<<endl;
    d = s.insert({4,{0,4}});
    cout<<(d.first)->first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.first<<" "<<(d.first)->second.second<<endl;
}
```

*Output:*

```
4 6 10
4 0 4
```

Why does the set not add a different pair in the first case? I thought the extra condition only decides the order, and doesn't differentiate between elements.

Comment: Because you thought wrong?

Comment: Please do tell: Who told you to include that header? We must make sure to warn people off against taking advice from that source.

Comment: @KerrekSB You mean <bits/stdc++.h>? Whats wrong with it  other than being non-standard (its useful for coding contests AFAIK)?

Comment: @KerrekSB people use it in competitive programming for most of the time on platform like codeforces, codechef, topcoder etc. It is much quicker to code your solution than writing all the header files individually. Although it is not a good practice to include such header.

Comment: @Rishit: You mean there's a real-time constraint on how long you can take to type out the source code? Hm. I suppose you could have a ready-made file at hand locally to copy-paste from... [Edit.] Oh, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011), apparently the host has that header precompiled, so it may be more efficient to compile the program.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, copy-paste does work which is why most of people keep a template file with all necessary headers included. Yes, time taken to type source code does account for score. Faster you code, faster you will be able to submit fetching more points.... [Edit.] Good link!

Comment: @KerrekSB all-in-one headers help for setups using precompiled headers

Comment: @M.M: Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first comparator only takes the first item of the pair in consideration. When you try to insert the second pair, it is considered equal to the already inserted pair, and thus not inserted.

Instead, you get back the object that was already inserted in the set, which is the expected behavior.

Remember, a set, by definition, only has one instance of a particular object, and your comparator helps it to state how 2 objects compare to each other.

Comment: Note: without using a custom comparator, the `std::set` is able to distinguish between (a,(b,c)) and (a,(d,e)).