# Entering an Integer then a string with spaces c++

Tags: c++

How can i cin an integer then a string "with spaces"
this is my code

```
int x;string s;
    cout<<"Enter Integer"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter the string with spaces"<<endl;
    //if i used cin>>s here then it will not read all the text because it has spaces 
    // is i used getline(cin,s); then it will not read any thing
```

Comment: Why #include <bits/stdc++.h>?

Comment: What did you try? Also *WHY* does everyone keep including `<bits/stdc++.h>`??

Comment: <bits/stdc++.h> or any other one whatever

Comment: @DeiDei: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c (apparently it was recommended by a blog once).

Comment: Yes I know this , What about the problem itself

Comment: @GregHewgill Oh, so it's basically when you're too lazy to include the individual appropriate standard headers. Make sense.

Comment: @AhmedElectrony The problem itself is easily solvable if you google "how to enter string c++". The fact that there is an int before it matters not.

Comment: no it matters
and the string is with spaces so that the only way i found to read it was to getline and this didn`t work when there is an integer before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are likely having is that the `cin >> x` reads *only* the digits of the number you type, and not the following newline. Then, when you do a `cin >> s` to read a string, the input processor sees the newline and returns only an empty string.

The solution is to use a function that is designed to read whole lines of input, such as `std::getline`. Do not use the extraction operator `>>` for interactive input.

Answer (score 0):

To read a string with spaces [use `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

## But!

Pay attention to what happens with `>>` when it hits a delimiter. It stops and leaves the delimiter int he stream. This is not a problem so long as you only use `>>` as `>>` will discard all of the whitespace. `std::getline` will capture that whitespace, and a common usecase is

```
user types in number and hits enter
user types in string and hits enter
```

So what happens? `>>` extracts the number and stops when it hits whitespace. This leaves the end of line put in the stream by pressing enter in the stream. `std::getline` comes along and the first thing it sees is... end of line. `std::getline` stores an empty string and immediately returns. Now the program processes an empty string and the user, still expecting to type in a string enters a string that will be read by some future read, possibly putting the input stream into an error case and certainly giving the user a surprise.

A common solution is [to use `ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to consume any data still in the stream up to and including the end of line before prompting the user for input and calling `std::getline`.