# How to sort map<int,pair<int,int> > according to second element only?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have created Cmp() function to use as a Comparator.But Iam getting error.
I have written this code .It shows error:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct cmp
    {
        bool operator() (multimap<int,pair<int,int> > a, multimap<int,pair<int,int> > b)
            {
                if(a->second.second>b->second.second)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }
    };
int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int test,i;
    long long sum=0;
    cin>>test;
    while(test--)
    {
        multimap<int, pair<int,int>,cmp > mymap;
        multimap<int, pair<int,int> >::iterator it;
        int n,days,d,t,s;
        cin>>n>>days;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>d>>t>>s;
            mymap.insert(make_pair(d,make_pair(t,s)));
        }
        for(it=mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end();it++)
        {
            cout<<it->first<<"  "<<it->second.first<<" "<<it->second.second<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives error :

> In member function 'bool cmp::operator()(std::multimap >, std::multimap >)':
>
> ```
>  [Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::multimap<int, 
> std::pair<int, int> >'
> ```

Is there any other way without using **struct Cmp() function?**

> ```
> eg:- suppose i have
>
> (3,(2,300))
> (3,(1,400))
> (3,(2,500))
> (2,(3,100))
> (2,(2,500))
> (1,(5,100))
>
> I want output like this:
> (1,(5,100))
> (2,(2,500))
> (2,(3,100))
> (3,(2,500))
> (3,(1,400))
> (3,(2,300))
>
>    Only the second element of pair<int,int> sorted decreasingly.
> ```

Comment: You can't sort a map by it's values. Perhaps you were looking for a `std::set` instead? Did you mean to invert your key and your value?

Comment: You are not passing to function `operator()` by pointer but by value. So addressing like `a->second.second` doesn't work. Why don't you try to pass by reference.

Comment: ok..Iam going for  std::set...Thanks

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is (a) not a standard file, and (b) is a bad practice because using it you don't get to learn to individual includes for the various bits of the standard library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The basis of the question doesn't make sense. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap):

> The order of the key-value pairs whose keys compare equivalent is the order of insertion and does not change.

You can't dictate the order of the *values*. If you need them sorted, you'll need to either copy them into a new container first or put them in a new container to begin with.

Also, the `Compare` type compares the *keys*, not the *entire map*. There are examples in the linked reference as well.