# cygwin gcc-6.4.0 compiler

Tags: c++, gcc

I've reinstalled my windows today because of some bug's.I then installed cygwin and gcc compiler, but when I try to compile some file with **-std=c++14** tag it gives me errors. When I replace `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`with `#include<iostream>` it will process the compiling as well, but I want to use the **bits/stdc++.h** lib. Can anyone help me fix this?
[image]

Comment: please include the error scripts in a good format in the question rather than including a snapshot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c has a few details on why it might no longer be present, even thouhg a previous install did have it. General consensus is to only include the headers you need rather than this blanket include.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to use the bits/stdc++.h lib" - it's not a library, and you definitely don't want to use it. It's an implementation detail of some compilers, and nothing that should be included in your code. If you are being taught to use it, learn C++ from some other source.