# What is a segmentation fault and why do I keep getting one?

Tags: c++

I am working on a lexer and when I run the test program, I keep getting this error:

`Segmentation fault`

I read about the error and I am pretty sure that I am trying to write read only memory.
This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <string> split(string line) {
  vector <string> tokens;
  stringstream check1(line);
  string intermediate;

  while(getline(check1, intermediate, ';')) {
    tokens.push_back(intermediate + ";");
  }
  return tokens;
}

vector <vector<string>> lex(vector <string> tokens) {
  vector <vector<string>> lexed;
  lexed[0] = tokens;
  string token;
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
    token = tokens[i];
    cout << token;
  }
  return lexed;
}

int main() {
  string line = "print(32); print(54); print(432);";
  vector <string> tokens = split(line);
  vector <vector<string>> x = lex(tokens);
  for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
    cout << tokens[0][i] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: `vector <vector<string>> lexed;
  lexed[0] = tokens;` is wrong

Comment: segmentation fault = you are reading memory that you can't read (in poor words)... the "why"... is the same definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: If you used `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your vector elements, you would have gotten a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown at the offending `at()` call instead of a seg fault, thus making it easier for you to debug the problem.  For example [here is your program using at()](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e2fd599da201bce)

Comment: Using it along side `#include <iostream>` suggests that you do not know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does. Before you use anything in C++ you should [familiarize yourself with its purpose and how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c). But in this case [you're better off not directly using it at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many many causes of segfaults. Yours is here

```
vector <vector<string>> lexed;
lexed[0] = tokens;
```

`lexed` has zero size, so `lexed[0]` is an error, and likely to cause a segfault.

This would work

```
vector <vector<string>> lexed;
lexed.push_back(tokens);
```

Comment: How about `vector <vector<string>> lexed{ tokens };` ? Seems like a better solution to me

Comment: @JackDavis -- Change the line to `lexed.at(0) = tokens;`, and you will see what I stated in my comment in the main section.