# AtCoder DP Contest Q -I Coins (getting wrong answer may be using double)

Tags: c++

Link to Problem ->    https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_i

question Coins-I
Code I wrote gave wrong answer to TEST CASE 3

```
5
0.42 0.01 0.42 0.99 0.42
```

Expected output

```
0.3821815872
```

MY code output

```
0.382182
```

As the error is greater than 1e-9 it got WA

What I tried:

I made double to long double but still it doesn't give accuracy
is there any way to increase the accuracy when working with double in this question.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long double p[3000];

long double dp[3001][1501];



long double solve(int i,int tail_count){

    if(dp[i][tail_count]!=2){
        return dp[i][tail_count];
    }
    long double ans=0;

    if(i==1 && tail_count==0)return p[1];

    else if(i==1 && tail_count>0)return (long double)1;

    else if(tail_count==0)ans= p[i]*solve(i-1,tail_count);
    else ans= (p[i]*solve(i-1,tail_count)+(1-p[i])*solve(i-1,tail_count-1));

    dp[i][tail_count]=ans;
    return ans;
}


int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<3000;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<1500;j++){
            dp[i][j]=2;
        }
    }
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>p[i];
    }
    
    cout<<solve(n,(n-1)/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c

Comment: it will solve other problems that you didn't encounter yet. Same is true for 
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: when you write "Expected output" do you mean the first line is the correct and the second line is your wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of digits to be printed via output streams is controlled by their precision parameter. The default is 6 digits, if you want more you need to adjust it accordingly by [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) :

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(num_digits) << solve(n,(n-1)/2);
```

---

Most of your indexing is off by one. Valid indices of an array with `N` elements are `0` till (including) `N-1`. `dp` is `3001` x `1501` but you only use `3000` x `1500` and `p` leaves the first element unused. Perhaps the code is still correct, but at least your way of using indices is confusing. Also in case you know the size of the array only at runtime you could use a `std::vector`.