# How to define a special handle function when there is a template function also match?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, member-functions

I have a class with template function and a special function, which looks like:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{ 
 public:
  template <typename T>
  void test(const T& t) 
  {
    cout << "template " << t << endl;
  }

  void test(const std::string& s) {
    cout << "test " << s << endl;
  }
};

int main() 
{
  A a;
  a.test("asdas");
}
```

As you could see, there are two `test` function:

1. `template` function
2. special function which only match `std::string` input.

What I want is:

1. `test(1)` -> call `template` function `test<int>(1)`
2. `std::string str = "asd"; test(str);` -> call special function `test(str)`
3. `test("asd")` -> call special function `test(std::string str = "asd")`

How to achieve this?

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 5):

The `asdas` is not a `std::string`, rather a *[string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)* which can referred as `const char*`. That is why `a.test("asd")` was not calling the member `void test(std::string const& s)`.

---

> How to achieve this?

One way to fix is proving one more member overload

```
class A 
{
public:
    // ... code
    void test(std::string const& s) {
        cout << "test " << s << endl;
    }

    void test(const char* s) {   // overload for string literals
        test(std::string{s});
    }
};
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tbvj63d4b)

Alternatively, in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can [SFINAE the two functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

```
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    auto test(const T& t) // T can not be convertible to std::string
        -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value>::type
    {
        std::cout << "template " << t << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto test(T const& s) // T can be convertible to std::string
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value>::type
    {
        std::cout << "test " << s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4sxcej3Mx)

---

However, if you are able to at-least upgrade to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), you could use a *[string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)*, and pass the `std::string` to the `void test(std::string const& s)` (i.e. no more member overloads required)

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

a.test("asd"s);
//         ^^^
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/731hE73o8)

---

One step up, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we can decide what part of condition to be compiled/ discarded at compile time using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if).

```
class A 
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void test(const T& t)
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>)
        {
            std::cout << "template " << t << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "test " << t << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ps6zMYEqc)

---

Also have a read:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [How does #include <bits/stdc++.h> work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c)

Comment: SFINAE can even be done before C++11. It is just the provided tools/traits (such as `std::enable_if`) which have to be reimplemented.